# How can i group a column of a data-frame and count the instance of other related rows making them a column in new data-frame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Dataframe like this.

```
A     B
dog  yes
cat  yes
dog  no
cat  yes
```

and I need an output df like this.

```
A   yes No
dog  1  1
Cat  2  0
```

Comment: @ChrisA can you help me here?

Comment: Try `pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['B'],prefix='',prefix_sep='').groupby('A').sum().reset_index()`